# What are the results in the dt function?

Tags: r

Cans someone explain the results in a typical dt function? The help page says that I should receive the density function. However, in my code below, what does the first value ".2067" represent?The second value?

```
x<-seq(1,10)
dt(x, df=3) 
[1] 0.2067483358 0.0675096607 0.0229720373 0.0091633611 0.0042193538 0.0021748674
[7] 0.0012233629 0.0007369065 0.0004688171 0.0003118082
```

Comment: It doesn't give you "the density", true. Rather, `dt` gives you the value of the probability density function of a t-distribution with `df` degrees of freedom at position `x`.

Comment: May be this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function. That 0.2067 is the probability that the data take on value 1.

Comment: @Gopala: No. the probability that data distributed as any of the continuous probability distributions (including the _t_-dist) takes any particular value is always 0. (This being one of the enduring puzzles of "real analysis".)  If Wikipedia actually says what you say it does, then someone should correct it, but I rather doubt that's what is said.

Answer (score 0):

Two things were confused here:

`dt` gives you the density, this is why it decreases for large numbers:

```
x<-seq(1,10)
dt(x, df=3) 
[1] 0.2067483358 0.0675096607 0.0229720373 0.0091633611 0.0042193538 0.0021748674
[7] 0.0012233629 0.0007369065 0.0004688171 0.0003118082
```

`pt` gives the distribution function. This is the probability of being smaller or equal x.

This is why the values go to 1 as x increases:

```
pt(x, df=3)
 [1] 0.8044989 0.9303370 0.9711656 0.9859958 0.9923038 0.9953636 0.9970069 0.9979617 0.9985521 0.9989358
```

Answer (score 0):

A "probability density" is not really a true probability, since probabilities are bounded in [0,1] while densities are not. The integral of densities across their domain is normalized to exactly 1. So densities are really the first derivatives of the probability function. This code may help:

```
plot( x= seq(-10,10,length=100), 
      y=dt( seq(-10,10,length=100), df=3) )
```

The value of 0.207 for dt at x=1 says that at x=1 that the probability is increasing at a rate of 0.207 per unit increase in x. (And since the t-distribution is symmetric that is also the value of dt with 3 df at -1.)

[image]

A bit of coding to instantiate the dt(x,df=3) function (see `?dt`) and then integrate it:

```
> dt3 <- function(x) { gamma((4)/2)/(sqrt(3*pi)*gamma(3/2))*(1+x^2/3)^-((3+1)/2) }
> dt3(1)
[1] 0.2067483
> integrate(dt3, -Inf, Inf)
1 with absolute error < 7.2e-08
```